# How to resize UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've a `UIImageView`  called `img`.

How do I change it's size, let's say, increase it by `1.0` each time a press a button ?

Comment: Did you search a bit ? And finally did you try something ? It looks like a basic question.

Comment: Yes, and haven't found any good info unfortunately. I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by setting a different frame (and an appropriate content mode). For example:

```
- (IBAction) buttonWasPressed
{
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectInset([imageView frame], -20, -20)];
}
```

Note that this only changes the view size, not the underlying image data.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you need is to adjust this `size` of `UIImageView`, not really change size of `UIImage`. You can assign a new frame value of this UIImageView.

```
CGRect newFrame = img.frame;
newFrame .size.width += 1;
newFrame .size.height += 1;
img.frame = newFrame ;
```